# Reusing Blade Template in different tabs

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have body.blade.php in table folder that displays an array passed from controller to view

```
@include('table.body', [$cols, $rows, $table_no])
```

Now, I have converted that array into percentage and would like to show that too. I passed the $table_no and $table_percentage. In the view I have coded

```
Tab 1 - View Numbers

@include('table.body', [$cols, $rows, $table_no])

Tab 2 - View Percentage

@include('table.body', [$cols, $rows, $table_percentage])
```

I have duplicated the body.blade.php for $table_no and $table_percentage but wish to know if there is an elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass different array as an array

```
@foreach($tables as $table_no)
      @include('table.body', [$cols, $rows, $table_no])
@endforeach
```